Como hacer que funcione correctamente el campo tipo IDENTYTI al insertar datos
Cordial saludo. En la actualidad estamos contruyendo un aplicativo que nos esta presentando una novedad a la hora de insertar los datos en la base de datos. El usuario en el aplicativo nos entrega una informacion importante, la cual se procede a insertar en la base de datos. La tabla en la base de datos, tiene un campo de tipo IDENTYTI que nos esta generando problemas, ya que a la hora de insertar los datos y no poner dicho campo (asumiendo que al no ponerlo, el sistema hara el autoincremento normalmete) nos aparece el error que indica que no podemos ingresar explicitamente datos a un campo tipo IDENTYTI. El error aparece debido que al no poner dicho campo en la insercion de datos, el sistema le asigna el valor cero implicitamente. Como podemos hacer entonces para que ese campo no se ponga implicitamente en el valor cero y el campo IDENTYTI funciona correctamente haciendo el autoincremento. Les compartimos el modelo de la tabla que cuyo dato Rgistro es IDENTYTI.
public class LlanHistoria
{
    [Key]
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? equipo { get; set; }
    public int Ubicacion { get; set; }
    public decimal Horometro { get; set; }
    public decimal Odometro { get; set; }
    public string? operacion { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_1 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_2 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_3 { get; set; }
    public decimal presion { get; set; }
    public int salida { get; set; }
    public string? estado { get; set; }
    public string? situacion { get; set; }
    public string? observaciones { get; set; }
    public int bodega { get; set; }
    public string? usuario { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaIngreso { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
} 

De igual forma, nos parece importante que puedan observar el metodo que hace la inserción de los datos para que puedan observar que el dato Registro no es tenido en cuenta para que se pueda hacer el autoincremento que realiza el tipo IDENTYTI.
/// <summary>
    /// 2024-02-05: Lista de datos por salida de llantas.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ListaWAPIL">Lista traida desde el cliente.</param>
    /// <param name="Usuario">Datos del usuario.</param>
    [HttpPost("/Llantas/Insertar/Salida/", Name = "PostLlantasInsertarSalida")]
    public void PostLlantasInsertarSalida(List<TemLlantasSalidasInsertar> ListaWAPIL)
    {
        foreach (TemLlantasSalidasInsertar b in ListaWAPIL)
        {
            // 2024-02-28: Obtengo los datos de la tabla de salidas
            var t1 = GetLlantasSalidasRegistro(b.RegistroSalida);
            var t2 = t1.FirstOrDefault();
            // 2024-03-08: Aqui obtengo el valor del ultimo registro que tiene la tabla.
            // Constante que utilizaremos en la lista para definir el campo situacion.
            var t3 = GetLlantasUltimoRegistro();
            string OperacionViewState = "Montaje";
            string SituacionMontaje = "ok";
            string SituacionDesmontaje = "desmontada";
            // 2024-02-28: Creo la lista a insertar definiendo los campos
            var q1 = new LlanHistoria
            {
                id = b.IdLlanta,
                Fecha = t2.fecha,
                equipo = t2.equipo,
                Ubicacion = b.UbicacionLlanta,
                Horometro = b.HorometroEquipo,
                Odometro = b.OdometroEquipo,
                operacion = b.OperacionLlanta,
                prof_1 = b.ProfundidadLlanta,
                prof_2 = b.ProfundidadLlanta,
                prof_3 = b.ProfundidadLlanta,
                salida = t2.numero,
                estado = b.EstadoLlanta,
                // 2024-02-28: Defino la operación segun el tipo de operación.
                situacion = b.OperacionLlanta == OperacionViewState ? SituacionMontaje : SituacionDesmontaje,
                bodega = t2.bodega,
                usuario = b.Usuario,
                FechaIngreso = DateTime.Now,
                FechaInsert = DateTime.Now
            };

            context.LlanHistoria.Add(q1);
            // 2024-03-08: Inserto el registron en la tabla.
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

Especificamente este es el error que nos aparece al insertar la información en la tabla que tiene el dato Registro que es del tipo IDENTYTI.
ApiException: The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (500).

ApiException: The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (500).
Status: 500 Response: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'LlanHistoria' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException e
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
Para nosotros es muy importante que el autoincremento del IDENTYTI funcione correctamente.
Agradecemos la ayuda que puedan brindarnos.

Cordial saludo. Logramos identificar que para que en el modelo de la tabla, el sistema pueda identificar que es un campo de tipo IDENTITY, es necesario expresarlo explicitamente con esta linea:
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Luego de hacer esto, C# deje de ponerle el valor cero de manera implicita a dicho campo y comienza a ponerle el autoincremento. La correccion la hicimos en el modela de la tabla, quedano asi:
public class LlanHistoria
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? equipo { get; set; }
    public int Ubicacion { get; set; }
    public decimal Horometro { get; set; }
    public decimal Odometro { get; set; }
    public string? operacion { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_1 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_2 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_3 { get; set; }
    public decimal presion { get; set; }
    public int salida { get; set; }
    public string? estado { get; set; }
    public string? situacion { get; set; }
    public string? observaciones { get; set; }
    public int bodega { get; set; }
    public string? usuario { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaIngreso { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
} 

Luego de esto, hicimos la debidas pruebas, validando que se insertaran los datos y que el autoincremento fuera correcto.
